# Why isn't my code returning the "maximum" number of consecutive 1's for the specific input "524275"?

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to solve [HackerRank Day Of Code 10](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-binary-numbers).

In short, the task is to find the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the binary representation of a decimal number. In my code I've tried to use two variables: `count` and `hold`. `count` increases by 1 whenever the current position of the string and the previous position are both 1. Whenever the i'th position is 0, `count` 's value is assigned to the variable `hold`. In the following iterations if ever the value of `count` exceeds that of `hold` then the value of `count` is assigned to `hold`. In this way the maximum number of consecutive 1's is stored in `hold`. Finally I'm printing the value of `hold`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter decimal number");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    String binary = Integer.toString(n,2);
    int count=1;
    int hold=0;
    if(binary.equals("0"))
        System.out.println(0);
    else
    {
    for(int i=0;i<binary.length();i++)
    {
        if(i==0){}
        else if(binary.charAt(i-1)=='1' && binary.charAt(i)=='1')
        {
            count++;
        }
        if(count>hold)
           hold=count;
        if(binary.charAt(i)=='0')
        {
            hold=count;
            count=1;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(hold);
    }
  }
}
```

My code isn't working for the sample input "524275" which converts to "1111111111111110011" in binary. The output comes out to be 2 which is strange. my code is written such that the "maximum" number of consecutive 1's are returned. Where did I go wrong? I tried dry running the code mentally but can't spot the mistake yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After processing the first `15` ones in with the for loop, `hold` will actually have the value `15`. Then you meet the first zero, and `if(binary.charAt(i)=='0') { hold=count; count=1; }` will reset `count` to `1`. But then you immediately find another zero, and the same code `if(binary.charAt(i)=='0') { hold=count; count=1; }` stores `1` in `hold` and you loose the information `15`.

An easy solution is just to remove the line `hold=count;` in this line. You already set `hold` three lines above. (And correctly, because you only do it if `count` is bigger then the previous best value.

---

The approach is quite complicated. If you want an easier approach. The code should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
int current_consecutive_ones = 0;
int best_consecutive_ones = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++)
{
    if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
        current_consecutive_ones++;
    else
        current_consecutive_ones = 0;

    if (current_consecutive_ones > best_consecutive_ones)
        best_consecutive_ones = current_consecutive_ones;
}
System.out.println(best_consecutive_ones);
```

Comment: Great catch! Thank you. I get it now. :)

Comment: It is always advised to use braces(`{}`) in `if` statements and loops.